# Need to run two actions inside a scheduled task. Need one to run after the first finishes

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have powershell code to create a task that "ghosts" a harddrive using ghost.exe. I need to create a single task that first runs ghost.exe with all my parameters, then after it is finished, runs the next action that will verify the image using a powershell script.

The trick is telling the task to wait until the backup is created, then run the verify. In my attempts, it starts the backup then immediately tries to verify. How can I do this?

Line:

```
 cmd /c schtasks /Create /RU 'SYSTEM' /SC once /TN hotghost /SD $startdate 
 /ST $starttime /TR $hotghosttask
```

/TR is "task to run" but I cannot add another /TR to add another action.

Comment: It would be nice if you try something before asking general questions.

Comment: @montonero I've been working on this all week, thanks.

Comment: Without any code you'll not get any answer here.

Comment: @montonero edited.

Comment: What is `$hotghosttask`?  An executable path, or it must be a script if both cloning and verification operations are being started?  Either way it sounds like Ghost is not being executed synchronously.  By the way, you don't need to use `cmd /c` to invoke another executable (`schtasks.exe`); you can just call `schtasks` directly.  You might consider looking into the [`New-ScheduledTask` command](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask) of the [`ScheduledTasks` module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=win10-ps), too.

Comment: @BACON $hotghosttask is the task. It's just ghost.exe \clone basically. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: To clarify, is the task directly referencing `ghost.exe` and whatever appropriate parameters directly?  Or a script that calls `ghost.exe`?  How was the verification being started such that it ran concurrent to Ghost?

Comment: @Clev you can write a script with all required actions (imaging and verifying) and run it as a task. This should solve the synchronization issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an existing item that you're waiting on a change for and your roughly know how long the "ghost" usually takes, a simple solution would be to just build a control in the PowerShell-script that will be run afterwards, to wait for a new LastWriteTime on the image. In the below example, when the $temp.LastWriteTime matches the current month, day, year and hour, the script will continue.

See the below example:

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy hh:"

do {
$temp = Get-Item C:\temp\temp.txt
}
    until($temp.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:") -eq $date)
Write-Host "Starting image verification..." 
[your code begins here]
```

Another alternative would be to create a temp-file that's generated after the first task has been completed and just use a do/until loop until the statement is true.

```
do {
$temp = Test-Path C:\temp\temp.txt
}
    until($temp -eq $true)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the creation process varies greatly between computers for the first suggestion. I will try out the second one.

Comment: Creating a temp-file when the task has been completed is usually the way to go then - same goes when the second script has been completed, remove the temp-file.

Comment: Do you know how to generate a temp file after the first task is completed?

Comment: That wholly depends on how you can interact with the first task and since I don't know that, I have another recommendation based on just looking at the scheduled job that does the "ghost".

I would set up the second task to trigger when the first task has been completed.
You can create a second scheduled task that would trigger when the first task has reported EventID 102 (Completed). You can build custom event selections for when tasks should be run and here's a great guide describing the process: http://woshub.com/schedule-task-to-start-when-another-task-finishes/